# git with directory-became-submodule: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout

Tags: git, git-submodules

I work with a fork, `R-fork`, of a large repository `R` (developed by people with whom I have almost no contact). `R` has a dozen submodules.
On `R-fork`, I work in my own branch `mybranch`, which I frequently rebase.

Today, I needed to look something up in `oldbranch`, but my `git checkout` command resulted in

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        Sdir/a
        Sdir/b
```

`a` and `b` are files that are definitely part of the versioned tree structure, but have recently switched their status:
In `oldbranch`, `Sdir` was part of `R`, but then it was converted into a new submodule `S` of `R` and that is how it is in `mybranch`.

The commit that introduced the submodule deleted *three* files from `Sdir`: `a`, `b`, `c`. All three (and several others) now exist as versioned files in the `S` repo. Why did only `c` behave like it should?

Even more strangely, when do `cd Sdir; git ls-files -t`, all three are shown as cached (tracked) files and I do not see why `R` can view them as untracked.

What is my problem?

Comment: I can't divine "Why did only `c` behave like it should?". In these cases, it is best to set up a working example. It sounds like you should only need two repositories to duplicate the situation.

Comment: @lmat-ReinstateMonica after deleting `a`, `b`, and `c`, all three should be gone from `R` and only exist in `S`, but somehow only `c` appears to have done so; `a` and `b` still kind of hang around -- or whatever it is that provokes that error message, I have no idea.

Comment: I understand that happened to you, but when I do it, it works properly. You'll need to create a list of instructions that anyone can reproduce at any time. You saw something funny in your repo, and it's not likely that anyone has any idea what happened.

Answer (score 1):

### A design limitation (I guess) of how git handles submodules

`git checkout` is simply not good enough in this case:
Despite the fact that I do not care about the contents of `Sdir`, I probably need to use `git checkout --recurse-submodules`, because otherwise the existing submodule contents get in the way of the newly arriving base-repository files such as `a` and `b`. (With this explanation, the problem should hit `c` as well, though.)

Unfortunately, `git checkout --recurse-submodules` is also not good enough, because git needs to check out the superproject *first* before it can know what is the matter with the submodules.
But the conflict of the `Sdir/a` file coming from `oldbranch` and the existing `Sdir/a` file, which from the perspective of the superproject is untracked, happens directly *while* checking out the superproject.

Not easy to solve for the git designers.

#### As a git user...

...you can help yourself in a clean manner by `git submodule deinit Sdir` before the `checkout`.